# What happens when you await a failed task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a theoretical question to you. What happens if I await the Result of a Task inside another task? I want to know if my current system will work afterwards.

A task gets launched and does some stuff. At some point that task might need another one in order to process data which the current task is not able to process by itself. So I use await to ensure that the current task won't continue as long as he has not the result of the helper task. But what happens if the helper fails? Will the current task remain locked?

Can I avoid this deadlock somehow (without changing the system itself - task inside task)?

Comment: How about writing a simple test code and watching the result?

Comment: You can't `await` the `Result`, you can await the task.  If it is failed, it will throw an exception

Comment: Sure I could write test code, but this would take much longer than asking here. And it shouldn't be too much of effort answering this :) Otherwise I'm very sorry. Sorry, my fault. Of course I meant await the task. So theoretically the "await" throws an exception if the awaited task fails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A task gets launched and does some stuff. At some point that task might need another one in order to process data which the current task is not able to process by itself. So I use await to ensure that the current task won't continue as long as he has not the result of the helper task. But what happens if the helper fails? Will the current task remain locked?

The core idea behind `async` and `await` is that asynchronous code works just about the same as synchronous code.

So, if you have synchronous code like this:

```
void HelperMethod()
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
}

void DoStuff()
{
  HelperMethod();
}
```

then you would expect `DoStuff` to propagate the `InvalidOperationException` from the helper method. Similarly, that's what happens with asynchronous code:

```
async Task HelperMethodAsync()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("test");
}

async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    await HelperMethodAsync();
}
```

That is, `DoStuffAsync` will also propagate the `InvalidOperationException`.

Now, it doesn't work *exactly* the same way, of course, since it must be asynchronous, but the general idea is that all your control flow such as `try`/`catch`, `for` loops, etc, all "just work" for asynchronous code very similarly to synchronous code.

What's *actually* going on is that when `HelperMethod` ends with an `InvalidOperationException`, the exception is caught and placed on the returned `Task`, and the task is completed. When the `await` in `DoStuffAsync` sees that the task has completed, it examines its exceptions and re-raises the first one (in this case, there is only one, the `InvalidOperationException`). And it re-raises it in a way that preserves the call stack on the exception. This in turn causes the `Task` returned from `DoStuffAsync` to be completed with that same exception.

So, under the covers `async` and `await` are doing a bit of work to ensure that you can just call other methods with `await` and use `try`/`catch` the same way as you would in synchronous code. But most of the time you don't have to be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. Another question related to this: When I call "task.Result" (or otherwise task.Wait() ), then it really get's locked, doesn't it? Is this a possible Deadlock source, or will it be safe?

Comment: I believe you're referring to [a deadlock scenario I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: What coincidence. I really had just that scenario and it was not even the problem I initially worried about. But still very helpful because this scenario occurs now at exactly that position I thought it could: My already asynchronous running method (the method itself is not async but it runs on a second thread) creates another task and has to wait for it to finish. Same problem :-/ So I really have to redesign my whole system in order to have async methods which can await those tasks...

Answer (score 4):

It's really easy to test.  For example:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
public async Task DoFaultedTaskThrowOnAwait()
{
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception("Error 42"); });
  await task;
}

[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(AggregateException))]
public void DoFaultedTaskThrowOnWait()
{
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception("Error 42"); });
  task.Wait();
}
```

Both tests pass, notice that `Wait` throws an `AggregateException`, and `await` throws the `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if I await the Result of a Task inside another task?

You can only `await` a `Task.Result` if it is an `awaitable` (meaning it has a `GetAwaiter` method). This is rarely the case. I assume you mean `await` on an inner Task.

> But what happens if the helper fails? Will the current task remain locked?

First, im not sure what you mean by "locked". The task isn't locked while you `await` on the inner task. Control is yielded back to the calling method until that inner task completes. If that inner task fails and you fail to properly handle that exception, you parent task will fault as well. You need to make sure you handle exceptions gracefully:

```
var task = 
  Task.Run(async () =>
           {
                 try
                 {
                        await AsyncHelper.DoSomethingAsync();
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                       // Handle exception gracefully
                 }
           });
```

If you `await` on the parent Task, you'll notice the inner exception propogating from the unhandled inner Task.

> Can I avoid this deadlock somehow?

I see no reason why your code should deadlock in this specific case. Not sure why this worries you.