# C# Http Post issue

Tags: c#, json

I am having trouble with this code that worked before at one point.

```
    public static async Task<Response> PushTest() {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Access-Token" , key ); //PROBLEM WAS HERE FOR SOME REASON
        //PROBLEM CODE
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Access-Token" , key );
        Uri url = new Uri(BaseUrl + "pushes");
        Dictionary<string,string> data =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data.Add( "body" , "TestBody" );
        data.Add( "title" , "TestTitle" );
        data.Add( "type" , "note" );
        data.Add( "email" , Email );
        HttpContent jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new KeyValuePairConverter()), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage post = await client.PostAsync(url, jsonContent); // DEBUG POINT
        // WORKS NOW
        string responseString = await post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // DOESNT RETURN NULL TO THE MAIN METHOD ANYMORE
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>( responseString );
    }

    private static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        Task<Response> n = PushTest();
        Response r = n.Result;
        Console.WriteLine( "Done" );
    } // DEBUG POINT
}
```

Summary:

Originally would not work because it would not make it past the post request, even with the better code for Tasks and async.

I don't know anything about Async or Tasks in C#, Only java. After fixing the code to the suggested fixes and focusing on Tasks, The actual problem was with the Authorization Header. Who knows why that is would be a better answer for me at this point. Switching to Add() instead fixed this issue. Will Research this.

Comment: Look into the difference between `async void` and `async Task`

Comment: That isn't helping at all. I've tried to convert it into an async Task and it's still not posting.

Comment: Then do more than just that and actually *look into the difference*. Put an effort into the hint I gave

Comment: Can you look at the code and tell me why it doesn't work now and why it did before? I can go and look into all the differences between this if I know the code I've written isn't garbage. I've already dumped 10 hours on this.

Comment: If it's an issue of stopping too quickly and ending before it's finished, surely it would be done within 10 seconds. If that's the issue, then why isn't it working.

Comment: Your code is most probably throwing an exception in the line that you have pointed out. Are you able to step through your code using the debugger, or is it terminated in the same way? Maybe it would help wrapping the `async` calls in `try/catch` blocks. This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26079132

Comment: I can't. It's just quitting. Dying. No trace, no error, nothing. The only thing close to an error i can find is a missing PDB for newtonsoft.json. There used to be try catch blocks until they weren't helping. Like I said, most of this code was fine, then it wasn't. No idea what is different. Not errors or anything. Just quits at  HttpResponseMessage  post = await client.PostAsync(url, jsonContent);

Answer (score 0):

`PushTest()` is a `Task<T>` so you wouldn't need to make a new `Task` out of the returned `T` (wait does that make sense?).

Try doing

```
Task<PostResponse> n = PushTest();
PostResponse r = n.Result;
```

Assuming you actually need the PostResponse because nowhere in your code are you actually using it (Hint: maybe try returning *something*).

Comment: This works better, but, this is not the real issue. If it came down to coding practices, I'm doing it totally wrong. But as I said in the start and the comments, I'm trying to debug this line by line, and it quits after the post request. It doesn't close before it's finished. It just never does anything.

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear when I read it...you have to look through the request/response, and enable your exceptions as you debug. Try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to see what's going on when you send your request to the server

Comment: Check out the opening question again. That'll shed some light on what was wrong. I put comments in to show where it was bugging out.

Comment: Again I recommend using something like Fiddler to see behind the scenes. The server you're bugging obviously did not like the request ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will get this fiddler thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt to set the header value, you used `DefaultRequestHeader.Authorization` to set the header value:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Access-Token" , key );
```

This will generate an Authentication Header with a scheme of `Access-Token` and the value of `key` as the auth token. The first argument of the `AuthenticationHeaderValue` ctor is the scheme, not the HTTP Header name.

Here is the resulting HTTP request assuming the `key` value is `foo`:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Access-Token foo
```

But, based on your update to fix the code sample, where you use `.Add()` instead, it seems the web api that you are calling uses a custom HTTP Header called `Access-Token` instead of the standard `Authorization` header. So, when you do:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Access-Token" , key );
```

it generates an HTTP Header called `Access-Token` with the value of `key`. Again assuming `key="foo"`, this will generate the following HTTP Request:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Access-Token: foo
```